# regex for filename.ext only

Tags: php, regex, image

I separate images from content like so:

```
list($img, $string) = explode('>', $string, 2);
$isSlashes = (stripos($img, '\\')!==false);
if ($isSlashes) {
  $img = stripslashes($img);
}
preg_match('|src=["\']([^"\']+)["\']|i', $img, $match);
if (empty($match[1])) {
  imgres_log('Image src not found in '.$img, 'error');
  imgres_joinContent($content, $img, $string, $isSlashes);
  continue;
}
$src = $match[1];
```

... it works usually except when the images are provided with a query string, eg: `img0880.jpg?itok=pUzE5f9d` which messes up everything. How do I remove the part after the `?` mark?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, to do what you say, just add ? into your regular expression.

```
preg_match('|src=["\']([^"\'?]+)["\']|i', $img, $match);
```

But, or actualy two buts.
1) if the image has a query string after ?, it is a part of the image URL. like image.jpg?foo=bar may refer to a different image than image.jpg?foo=baz.
2) you are allowing single and double quotes here. but what if there iss src="joe's_image.jpg" or src=image.jpg? both these cases are HTML valid and will fail with your script.

Solution: I suggest to use a DOM parser instead of regular expression.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
preg_match("~src=(\"|'|)(.*?)[\"|'| ]~si", $img, $match);
```

work for all condition

like

1)

```
src="image.jpg?dasd=a5fsd"
```

output

```
Array
(
  [0] => src="image.jpg?dasd=a5fsd"
  [1] => "
  [2] => image.jpg?dasd=a5fsd
)
```

2)

```
src='image.jpg?dasd=a5fsd'
```

output

```
Array
(
   [0] => src='image.jpg?dasd=a5fsd'
   [1] => '
   [2] => image.jpg?dasd=a5fsd
)
```

3)

```
src=image.jpg?dasd=a5fsd
```

output

```
Array
(
  [0] => src=image.jpg?dasd=a5fsd 
  [1] => 
  [2] => image.jpg?dasd=a5fsd
)
```